# Can you iterate a front matter collection variable in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

I'm trying to see if it's possible to iterate a variable in Jekyll for a testimonial block I'm implementing for a Jekyll site. Basically, I'd like to have an icon be multiplied by the number dictated in my collection. Is this even possible with liquid markdown? Here's a snippet:

```
{% assign star = "<i class="icon-star"></i>" %}
{% assign star = star | times:{{ testimonials.stars }} %}
```

I'm thinking there's better ways to do this, but I was curious what I could get away with front matter.

Answer (score 2):

To do it iterating, you can use a for loop appending the desired string to a variable:

```
{% assign star = '<i class="icon-star"></i>' %}
{% assign result = '' %}
{% for time in testimonials.stars %}
 {% assign result = result | append: star%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah! I never properly thanked you. This totally worked at the time I was writing the code. Thanks again. Better late than never!

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use a `for` block. You don't have to write multiple `assign` statements.

The following will render a `star` per the front matter key `rating` in any *page* using the code.
Modify the `for` bock as required.

```
{% assign star = '<i class="icon-star"></i>' %}
<div class="rating">
  {% for count in (1..page.rating)) %}
    {{ star }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Ref: [docs](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#allowed-collection-types)